# Show that such $x$ and $y$ exist

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Let $n$ be a positive integer which is not a square. Prove that for every integer $a$ relatively prime to $n$, there exist integers $x$ and $y$ satisfying
> $$ax \equiv y \pmod{n}\text{ with } 0<x<\sqrt n \text{ and } 0<|y|<\sqrt n$$

I'm unable to make any progress with this problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It's a pigeon-hole argument. The name Thue can help in search.

Comment: I dont know, maybe it helps that a criterion for solveability for such problems is, that $\gcd(a,n)\,|\, y$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just look at the expression $ax-y$ for $x,y$ $\in \{0,...,\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor \}$. Notice that there are $(\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor \ +1)^2 > n$ possibilities for $(x,y)$. Since there are $n$ possible values for $ax-y \pmod n$, by pigeonhole principle, there exists distinct $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2)$ in the previous range with $ax_1-y_1 \equiv ax_2-y_2 \pmod n$. So, $a(x_1-x_2) \equiv y_1-y_2 \pmod n$. Now, take $x=\lvert x_1-x_2 \rvert$, and, $y=y_1-y_2$ or $y=-(y_1-y_2)$ depending on the sign of $x$. Clearly, $x,\lvert y \rvert \in \{0,...,\sqrt n\}$. We also have $x\neq \sqrt n$, and, $\lvert y \rvert \neq \sqrt n$, since $n$ is not a square. All it remains is to show that $x\neq 0$, and, $\lvert y \rvert \neq 0$, which can be done easily using the fact that $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ are distinct and $(a,n)=1$.